# Will be executed everything which is into parenthesis first?

Tags: mysql, sql, parentheses

I have a query like this:

```
IF ( FALSE AND (SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE id = :id) ) THEN

    /* INSERT something here */

ENDIF;
```

All I'm trying to know is whether that `SELECT` statement which is into that condition will be executed or not?

As you know, that `INSERT` statement never run, because there is `FALSE` and `AND` in the condition, so the condition is always `FALSE`.

Now I just want to know that `SELECT` executes before that `IF`-statement? I'm saying that because I heard everything which is into parenthesis will be executed first in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation ([MySQL :: 13.3.1 Operator Precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html)) doesn't say it but it seems a short-circuit is followed. It would be necessary to confirm the information.

MariaDB gives more details: [MariaDB :: Operator Precedence :: Short-circuit evaluation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/operator-precedence/#short-circuit-evaluation).

Example:

```sql
mysql> SET @`out` := 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT (FALSE AND (SELECT @`out` := 0));
+----------------------------------+
| (FALSE AND (SELECT @`out` := 0)) |
+----------------------------------+
|                                0 |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @`out`;
+--------+
| @`out` |
+--------+
|      1 | -- <-- Not change
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT (TRUE AND (SELECT @`out` := 0));
+---------------------------------+
| (TRUE AND (SELECT @`out` := 0)) |
+---------------------------------+
|                               0 |
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @`out`;
+--------+
| @`out` |
+--------+
|      0 | -- <-- Change
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE**

```sql
mysql> SET @`out` := 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT (TRUE AND (SELECT @`out` := 1) AND FALSE);
+-------------------------------------------+
| (TRUE AND (SELECT @`out` := 1) AND FALSE) |
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                         0 |
+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @`out`;
+--------+
| @`out` |
+--------+
|      1 | -- <-- Change
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Nice examples, +1 .. To be sure, do you mean MySQL first of all evaluates all other conditions and then if all are `TRUE` then executes that subquery?

Comment: @Stack: The evaluation is done from left to right, see the update of the answer.

Comment: @Stack: See [MariaDB :: Operator Precedence :: Short-circuit evaluation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/operator-precedence/#short-circuit-evaluation). It can be useful.

Comment: I see, and what about this `(FALSE AND (SELECT @out := 1) AND TRUE)` ? `@out` will not change?

Answer (score 1):

About your code : it will do what you guess it will. It will execute the `SELECT` then evaluate the condition linked to your `IF`

This behavior is common to a lot of programming languages. When in doubt, use parenthesis.

Comment: I lot of programming languages use short-circuiting, which would mean the statement would _not_ be executed because the condition is known to be false regardless of the result of the query. It would be a nice idea to back up your answer with actual facts.